# Importing the datasets from the Book "Graph databases"

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Hopefully I am posting this question at the right place. I am reading the book "Graph Databases", [1](http://www.neotechnology.com/2013/02/graph-databases/) by Ian Robinson's early edition. Is there anyway to import the graphs from the book, so I could work out the book examples by myself?

Comment: One example I put up: http://console.neo4j.org/r/shakespeare

Answer (score 2):

We do plan on making most of the graphs available. The smaller graphs in e.g. Chapter 4 we'll put up on console.neo4j.org; the larger examples in Chapter 7 will be available as source code, including all the tests we wrote while writing the queries.

We're not quite ready to publish these, however. We're still revising all the examples based on feedback from technical reviews.

ian